# prompt user for input again after background process return

Tags: c, unix, process, background-process

I'm trying to build a job control shell and currently dealing with background processes. In this program, I fork a child process to handle each background process, and I get a prompt immediately following the fork. But the problem is that, when the background process returns, it print out the prompt message again. Could anybody help me the solve this issue? thanks ##

```
char prompt[] = "myShell";
set_sighandler_SIGCHLD();  //wait for background process return
while(1){
       char cmd[BUFFERSIZE] = "";
       write(1, prompt, sizeof(prompt));
       if(read(0, cmd, 1024) <= 1)){
              //parse command
              //and execute
       }
}
//Here is the background process.
int put_to_background(int (*func)(char** arg), char ** cmd){
     pid_t pid;
     if((pid = fork()) < 0){
         perror("fork");
         return -1;
     }
     else if(pid == 0){
         func(cmd);     //call the function the execute the command
         _exit(0);
     }
     else{
         if(setpgid(pid, 0)){
             perror("setpgid");
             return -1;
         }
         printf("running: %d\n", pid);

     }
```

After I called function, it immediately print out the prompt "myShell"(that's what I expected), but it prints out one more time after the background process returned.

I am still working on signal handling...

```
 JobList list;
 void sighandler(int signum, siginfo_t *sip, void *ucp){
     if(signum == SIGCHLD){
        pid_t pid;
        while((pid = waitpid(-1, NULL, WNOHANG)) > 0){
           Job * job = (Job*)malloc(sizeof(Job));
           job->pid = pid;
           insert(&list, job);  
       }
     }
     else if(signum == SIGTTOU){
       printf("SIGTTOU: pid = %d\n", (int) sip->si_pid);
     }
     else if(signum == SIGTTIN){
      printf("SIGTTIN: pid = %d\n", (int) sip->si_pid);
     }
 }  

int set_sighandler_SIGCHLD(){

struct sigaction sa;
sigemptyset(&sa.sa_mask);

sigaddset(&sa.sa_mask, SIGCHLD); 
sigaddset(&sa.sa_mask, SIGTTIN);
sigaddset(&sa.sa_mask, SIGTTOU);
sa.sa_sigaction = sighandler;
sa.sa_flags = SA_SIGINFO;
//sigprocmask(SIG_BLOCK, &sa.sa_mask, NULL);

if(sigaction(SIGCHLD, &sa, NULL)){
    perror("sigaction");
    return -1;
}
if(sigaction(SIGTTOU, &sa, NULL)){
    perror("sigaction");
    return -1;
}
if(sigaction(SIGTTIN, &sa, NULL)){
    perror("sigaction");
    return -1;
}
return 0;
```

}

Comment: I understand why you have not cluttered your question with the full definition of `set_sighandler_SIGCHLD()`, but would you post a suitable definition, anyway, to make it easier to reproduce your error?

Comment: More to the point, would it be reasonable for you to give a complete, compilable test case?

Comment: #I am still working on the signal handlers#

Comment: Fair enough.  However, you have evidently compiled and run some code or other such that, "when the background process returns, it prints out the prompt message again."  I cannot compile the code you list.  Would you like to give (hopefully not too long) code one *can* compile?

Comment: I think that you are doing your best to ask a good question, so I hope that your question does not get lost in Stackoverflow's Big Pile of old, unanswered questions.  However, I am not clever or patient enough to answer it in the form asked.  I still see an incomplete source file, without header inclusion and the like.  I happen to be logging off now for the day, so hopefully someone else will attend to the question.  Good luck.

Comment: It is not safe to call `malloc` inside a signal handler.  Have your signal handler assign a value to a global sig_atomic_t and *nothing* else.  Handle all the logic outside the signal handler.  (It is also unsafe to call `printf`)

Answer (score 0):

The `read` loop is being interrupted by the signal, so you print the prompt.  (That is, when the signal arrives, `read` immediately returns.) You can either check if read returns -1 and has returned due to `EINTR`, or try setting `SA_RESTART` to the signal handler.  Note that `SA_RESTART` does not always work (implementation dependent, many bugs in various implementations) and is, IMO, best avoided.